# Upper bound on a sum of measures over a countable partition of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I recently came across the following problem in a measure theory textbook:

> Let $P$ be a countable partition of $\mathbb{R}^d$ containing only elements of the Borel set $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Let $(\mu_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ and $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ such that $\forall n\geqslant 1$, $\mu_n(\mathbb{R}^d)\leqslant 1$ and $\mu(\mathbb{R})\leqslant 1$. Show that
>   $$\sum_{B\in P}|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|\leqslant 3\sup_{A\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)}|\mu_n(A)-\mu(A)|$$

The proof of this result only contains the following statement:

> Write $\displaystyle\sum_{B\in P}|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|$ as $\displaystyle\sum_{B\in \pi_1}|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|+\sum_{B\in \pi_2}|\mu_n(B)-\mu(B)|$ where $\pi_1=\{B\in P\mid\mu_n(B)\geqslant\mu(B)\}$ and $\pi_2=\{B\in P\mid \mu_n(B)<\mu(B)\}$.

It does not make sense to me, as there could be, say, 4 sets in $P$ such that the absolute difference of their measures is equal to the supremum, and therefore the stated inequality would not hold...

Have I missed something ? How does one establish this result ? And furthermore, where does this 3 come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hint, define

$$C = \bigcup_{B \in \pi_1} B\qquad\text{and}\qquad D = \bigcup_{B \in \pi_2} B.$$

Then $C,D \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, and

\begin{align}
\sum_{B \in \pi_1} \lvert \mu_n(B) - \mu(B)\rvert = \sum_{B \in \pi_1} \mu_n(B) - \mu(B) = \mu_n(C) - \mu(C) &\leqslant \sup_{A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lvert \mu_n(A) - \mu(A)\rvert, \\
\sum_{B \in \pi_2} \lvert \mu_n(B) - \mu(B)\rvert = \sum_{B \in \pi_2} \mu(B) - \mu_n(B) = \mu(D) - \mu_n(D) &\leqslant \sup_{A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lvert \mu_n(A) - \mu(A)\rvert.
\end{align}

Thus we have the sharper

$$\sum_{B \in P} \lvert \mu_n(B) - \mu(B)\rvert \leqslant 2\cdot\sup_{A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)} \lvert \mu_n(A) - \mu(A)\rvert.$$

And that makes it unclear where the $3$ comes from.

Comment: It makes way more sense now, thank you! I suppose the 3 should have been replaced by a 2 in the first place, so it may be a typo.